# How to get integers out of QCUT while creating Categories for DataFrame Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With two ndarrays:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,100, 10)
b = np.random.random_integers(low=9000, high=10000, size=(1000,))
```

I go ahead and create the DataFrame:

```
numbers =  np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':numbers})
```

Since the most of the numbers values (1000 numbers) fall in a range between 9,000 and 10,000 and only 10 numbers fall in a range between 1 and 100 I am using `qcut()` method to get the categories that are logically spaced by percentage of the numbers falling in each range:

```
df['cats'] = pd.qcut(df.a, 10)
print pd.value_counts(df['cats'])
```

which prints out:

```
[0, 9103]           102
(9630.4, 9717]      102
(9407, 9519]        102
(9307.4, 9407]      102
(9895.3, 10000]     101
(9717, 9810]        101
(9203.6, 9307.4]    101
(9810, 9895.3]      100
(9103, 9203.6]      100
(9519, 9630.4]       99
Name: cats, dtype: int64
```

Instead of "(9103, 9203.6]", "(9519, 9630.4]" labels that `qcut` generates I wish I could get the integer numbers such as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 and etc?

Comment: IIUC, I think you just want to use `labels=False` when calling [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html), i.e. `pd.qcut(df.a, 10, labels=False)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `labels=np.arange(10) + 1`

```
df['cats'] = pd.qcut(df.a, 10, labels=np.arange(10) + 1)
print pd.value_counts(df['cats'])

1     103
3     102
10    101
9     101
8     101
7     101
6     101
4     101
5     100
2      99
Name: cats, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution posted by root:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,100, 10)
b = np.arange(9000, 10000)

numbers =  np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':numbers})


df['cats'] = pd.qcut(df.a, 10, labels=False)

print df['cats'].value_counts()
```